# specified DSN contain an architecture mismatch on mnogosearch

Tags: odbc, 32bit-64bit, mismatch

We installed  the mnogosearch trail on our 64bit Windows server but as we are trying to connect the Mysql database through the mysql ODBC 5.2 we are getting an error "The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application " .[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MnoGoSearch is a 32-bit application.
You need to use 32-bit MySQL ODBC driver instead of 64bit mysql odbc driver.

[Here is the link for download](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/)